# How many processes can listen on a specific port?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, webserver

How many processes can listen on a specific port such as 80 ? and how the child processes of some application can use the same port to listen on ? Is there any difference between listening on a port or establishing a listening connection ?

Answer (score 9):

> Q: How many processes can listen on a specific port?

A: as many as you can spawn.

However for `SOCK_STREAM` sockets at least, and unless you use the `SO_REUSEPORT` option (new in Linux 3.9), a process cannot bind a socket to a local endpoint (address+port for TCP, filename for Unix...) if there's already another socket bound on that (or a listening one on that port with the wildcard address).

So unless you use SO_REUSEPORT, the only way to have different processes listen on the same port is to have their corresponding file descriptors pointing to the same *open file description* (to the same socket).

That happens automatically when you `fork()` a process. If fd 3 points to a listening TCP socket on the wildcard address and port 12345, both processes after the fork will be listening on that port on that fd (`zsh` syntax below):

```
$ zmodload zsh/net/tcp
$ ztcp -ld 3 12345
$ sleep 10 &
$ lsof -ni tcp:12345
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
zsh     26277 stephane    3u  IPv4 506354      0t0  TCP *:12345 (LISTEN)
sleep   26988 stephane    3u  IPv4 506354      0t0  TCP *:12345 (LISTEN)
```

For processes that are not related, the only way  (that I know) for a process to get access to that listening socket would be to use the [`SCM_RIGHT` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8481138) to pass fds (actually more like *open file descriptions*) between processes using unix domain sockets.

You'll notice that one argument to `listen()` is the *backlog*.

As soon as there's a socket listening on given endpoint, the kernel will start accepting incoming connections to that endpoint ([the backlog is a hint to the kernel as to how many it may accept that have not been `accept`ed by applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5111040)).

Then the first process that does an `accept()` on any of the fds that point to the listening socket (or any of the listening sockets with `SO_REUSEPORT`) will get the incoming connection. `accept()` creates a new socket, and returns a new fd to that `socket`. In turn, that fd can be duplicated (a new fd pointing to the same socket) and children processes will inherit that *connected* socket like they would the listening one.

Answer (score 3):

This answer discusses TCP on IPv4.

Only one process can **listen** for new connections. You'll get an "address already used" error if more than one processes attempt to claim the same port.

This is totally different from the amount of processes that are actively using that port.

Have a look at the following output:

```
remote          local        state
*:*           - 4.3.2.1:5000 LISTENING
1.2.3.4:12345 - 4.3.2.1:5000 CONNECTED
4.5.6.7:83247 - 4.3.2.1:5000 CONNECTED
```

What needs to be unique, is the 4-tuple `(remote-ip, remote-port, local-ip, local-port)`. As the `(remote-ip, remote-port)` in the LISTENING state is a `*:*`, only one process can listen.

The listening application will start a new thread/task/process on each incoming connection.

Comment: You can bind to specified address only as well (rather than to `*`) and remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are separate stacks.

Comment: You can have several processes listening on the same protocol:address:port as long as it's on file descriptors sharing the same open file descriptions (like children inheriting fds, or fds passed with SCM_RIGHTS).